# Quaternary operator for rendering in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have an object in state that can have 1 of 3 values. Im rendering something different in each case.

```
      {this.state.progress === 'choose' ? 'Choose your settings' : null}
      {this.state.progress === 'running' ? 'GO!' : null}
      {this.state.progress === 'done' ? 'Done' : null}
```

My code is working fine but there must be a shorter way to write this?

Comment: just use a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you can combine multiple quaternary operators it can get a little messy and hard to read. I would suggest another approach.

You can create a function that can return a value related to `this.state.progress`. This way if you add another option to the list of progress it will be easier to add and also you can handle the possibility of progress being empty/null/undefined and prevent a possible bug.

**Example**

```
getProgressText = () => {
  const { progress } = this.state;
  switch(progress) {
    case 'choose':
      return 'Choose your settings';
    case 'running':
      return 'GO!';
    case 'done':
      return 'Done';
    default:
      // handle empty/null/undefined/different value then what you expect
      break;
  }
}

render() {
  return(this.getProgressText())
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an object (or an [ES6 Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)) that will hold the response to each progress value:

Object (dictionary):

```js
const labels = {
  choose: 'Choose your settings',
  running: 'GO!',
  done: 'Done'
};

const progress = 'running'; // this.state.progress

const currentLabel = labels[progress] || null;

console.log(currentLabel);
```

ES6 Map:

```js
const labels = new Map([['choose', 'Choose your settings'],   ['running', 'GO!'], ['done', 'Done']]);

const progress = 'running'; // this.state.progress

const currentLabel = labels.get(progress) || null;

console.log(currentLabel);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd turn it into a separate function and call that instead:

```js
function getProgressText(progress) {
  switch (progress) {
    case 'choose':
      return 'Choose your settings'
    case 'running':
      return 'Go!';
    case 'done':
      return 'Done';
    default:
      return null;
  }
}

...

<MyComponent>{getProgressText(this.state.progress)}</MyComponent>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer - complicated logic should be moved to separate functions. It is cleaner and more extensible than any of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Shorter way :D :

```
const { progress } = this.state;
{ progress === 'choose' && 'Choose your settings' }
{ progress === 'running' && 'GO!' }
{ progress === 'done' && 'Done' }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const texts = {'choose': 'Choose your settings', ... }
```

and then:

```
{texts[this.state.progress]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to resolve your problem is additional method with switch/case operator.

```js
    
renderProgress = () => (
    switch(this.state.progress) {
      case 'choose': 
        return 'Choose your settings';
      case 'running': 
        return 'GO!';
      case 'done': 
        return 'Done';
      default:
        return null;
    }
);


render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.renderProgress()}
    </div>
  );
}
```